# No option to disable/enable Outlook notifications in Windows 10 settings

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook-2013, notifications

I have searched and found a lot of sites on how to enable/disable the Outlook notification in Windows 10. My problem is that I don't have this option under the *Notifications and actions*. I do see autoplay, focus assist, Display settings, etc.

Comment: Why not change this from within outlook itself?

Answer (score 2):

#### How to enable/disable the outlook notification in Windows 10

> **Enable Outlook Email Notifications in Windows 10**
>
> To turn on notification banners for new messages in Outlook with
>   Windows 10:
>
> 1. Open the Start menu in Windows.
> 2. Select Settings.
> 3. Open the System category.
> 4. Select Notifications & actions.
> 5. Enable Show app notifications under Notifications.
> 6. Select Outlook under Show Notifications from these apps.
> 7. Make sure Notifications is enabled.
> 8. Now make sure Show notification banners is enabled as well.

Source [Configure Outlook Email Notifications in Windows 10](https://www.lifewire.com/configure-outlook-email-notifications-1173647)

---

Comment: Thanks for your answere but I cannot go on with option 6 because because outlook is not in the list.